# Data transfer costs in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-transfer

How do I estimate for data transfer costs for applications running in AWS

1. Will there be a data transfer cost for traffic from AWS loadbalancer
   to the application running in a EC2 environment
2. Will there be a data transfer cost for files uploaded into S3 through an application
   running AWS EC2
3. Will there be a data transfer cost for files
   retrieved using AWS Cloudfront in a web application, by end users
   from within the country (say Russia)
4. Will there be a data transfer
   cost if the application running in AWS EC2 makes a call to an
   Elasticsearch instance running in https://cloud.elastic.co

Comment: 1) It depends, 2) It depends, 3) Yes, 4) Yes -- Data Transfer pricing is incredibly frustrating.

Comment: I have not found a way to accurately estimate bandwidth costs on AWS ahead of time. It is incredibly frustrating as another commenter mentioned. As much as I like AWS, I would recommend looking at companies in the Bandwidth Alliance if you are greatly concerned about data transfer costs: https://www.cloudflare.com/bandwidth-alliance/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Transfer is only charged for traffic exiting AWS and going to the Internet, although there is also a small charge for traffic between AZs and Regions.

[image: Data Transfer pricing]

From: [Understanding Data Transfer in AWS - Last Week in AWS](https://www.lastweekinaws.com/blog/understanding-data-transfer-in-aws/)